# Is an air gap required for our new Kinetico water softener?

Tags: water-softener

We're having a Kinetico water softener system installed today. They're planning on running the drain tube down the wash drain. We're a little concerned because they're not establishing an air gap but they're telling us the air gap is on the system and that this is how they do it nationwide. Anyone have any experience with these sytems? Is this true? If not, is there a way to fix this ourselves?

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a little late for you, given the question is some months old, however...

I have a Kinetico Premier Compact softener installed by the main water entry to the house.
It was installed about seven months ago by the local Kinetico distributor.

The drain tube does go to an air gap under the kitchen sink.

The installation manual states that this should be done, as shown here

[image: Kinetico Installation Prefix]